# Как изменить запятую на другой знак и убрать пробелы Java

Tags: java, строки

Есть, например, строка:

```
"Описание серий, аннотации , изданных книг    , Анонсы новых изданий, новости"
```

Как заменить запятую на символ "`|`", а если между словами или фразами есть пробелы - убрать их, чтобы в результате получить такую строку:

```
"Описание серий|аннотации|изданных книг|Анонсы новых изданий|новости"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно легко сделать при помощи [регулярных выражений](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

```
String text = "Описание серий, аннотации , изданных книг , Анонсы новых изданий, новости";
String value = text.replaceAll("\\s*,\\s*", "|");
System.out.println(value);
```

Вывод:

> Описание серий|аннотации|изданных книг|Анонсы новых изданий|новости

В данном коде я использовал метод `String.replaceAll(regex, replacement)`, где `replacement` это строка на которую будет произведена замена всех подстрок удовлетворяющих выражению `regex`.

Регулярное выражение:

```
\\s*,\\s*
```

означает - все подстроки, содержащие от нуля и больше пробелов перед запятой `\\s*` и столько же после нее.

Так же замену регулярными выражениями возможно произвести при помощи объектов класса `java.util.regex.Pattern` и `java.util.regex.Matcher`